# Value of field "type" must be one of (4,) in a Modal using discord.py 2.0

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to show the user a Modal after they display a button, which contains a dropdown select menu from which they can choose multiple options. This code has functioned in the past, but is not causing an exception. Specifically:

```
[2022-09-02 22:30:47] [ERROR   ] discord.ui.view: Ignoring exception in view <TestButtonView timeout=180.0 children=1> for item <Button style=<ButtonStyle.primary: 1> url=None disabled=False label='Test' emoji=None row=None>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\adria\PycharmProjects\sblBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ui\view.py", line 425, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
  File "C:\Users\adria\PycharmProjects\sblBot\main.py", line 1131, in test_button_callback
    await interaction.response.send_modal(TestModal())
  File "C:\Users\adria\PycharmProjects\sblBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\interactions.py", line 852, in send_modal
    await adapter.create_interaction_response(
  File "C:\Users\adria\PycharmProjects\sblBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\webhook\async_.py", line 220, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In data.components.0.components.0: Value of field "type" must be one of (4,).
```

I have reduced my code to the minimal reproducible example of my issue. Here is the code for the Modal:

```
class TestModal(discord.ui.Modal, title='Test'):

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)

    select = discord.ui.Select(
        placeholder='Select a tier.',
        options=[discord.SelectOption(label='test')]
    )

    async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.defer()
```

And here is the code for the view with the button (the f):

```
class TestButtonView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        self.add_buttons()

    def add_buttons(self):
        test_button = discord.ui.Button(label='Test', style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple)

        async def test_button_callback(interaction: discord.Interaction):
            await interaction.response.send_modal(TestModal())

        test_button.callback = test_button_callback

        self.add_item(test_button)
```

And finally, the command to send the button view:

```
@client.command(hidden=True)
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send(view=TestButtonView())
```

Comment: Discord removed this, it was unsupported and a bug in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ui.Modal`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html?highlight=ui%20modal#modal) does only support items with type `4`, which is a  [`ui.TextInput`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html?highlight=ui%20modal#textinput). Means [`ui.Select`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html?highlight=ui%20modal#select) is not a supported item (yet). 
**See Component Types table:** [Discord API Documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/message-components#component-object-component-types)

The error is quite inaccurate, but it's intended that the error handling is not done better because of future purposes. 
**See here:** [Add better errors for incorrect items added to modal](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/pull/8400#issuecomment-1229348780)